# RESTful - CodeIgniter 3.1.5 - Fatal Error, Call to undefined function factory

Tags: function, rest, codeigniter, factory

I'm trying to make "RESTful" using CodeIgniter 3.1.5 and libraries https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined factory function () in D:\AppServ\www\restful\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php on line 857
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to undefined function factory ()
Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php
Line Number: 857
Backtrace:
```

[image: Error Image]

(Not my code, but it is example from codeigniter-restserver)

Comment: Can you show how you're using that example?

Comment: http://localhost/restful/index.php/api/example/users

Comment: And what you have written in controller?

Comment: not yet. 
I only testing a example from codeigniter-restserver
---
        $users = [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com', 'fact' => 'Loves coding'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jim', 'email' => 'jim@example.com', 'fact' => 'Developed on CodeIgniter'],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Jane', 'email' => 'jane@example.com', 'fact' => 'Lives in the USA', ['hobbies' => ['guitar', 'cycling']]],
        ];

Comment: After cloning the repository, have you installed composer?

Comment: Yes, I do.......

Comment: This is the error like some method is not found in project

Comment: Line 857:
$data = $this->format->factory($data)->{'to_json'}();

Comment: Yeah I mean same

Comment: Just check format.php class exists in library directory and you are including it in your rest controller.

Comment: I've checking, but I do not know there's a mistake

Comment: Hiya Hurricane, at StackOverflow we don't add solved in title instead we accept the answer that works for us see [tour] to learn more. The accept is the green check next to answer that worked for you.

Comment: I am sorry...
Thank's for stackoverflow and Eduard Zapata

Answer (score 0):

enter in line 61 of autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','Format');
```

I solved it that way.

Comment: Yeahh.. Thanks my bro Eduard Zapata...
SOLVED
---
(autoload.php on folder config)